# Bash wrong spaces, quotes interpretation in variables

Tags: linux, bash

I see a weird behavior in shell scripts when I pass a variable with parameters to external ruby script
For example:

```
params="--val1=test --val2='test'"
ruby ./script.rb
```

causes ruby to output `'test'` for var2 instead of `test`.

If I just pass params directly without using a variable everything works just fine.

Comment: You didn't use the variable `params` at all. Please edit your question to show us what you really do.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify your question a bit?

From what I understand you have a shell script, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
PARAMS="--val1=test --val2='test'"
ruby ./script.rb $PARAMS
```

And in `script.rb` you print out the value for the command line parameter `val2`. In this case it's expected that it prints out `test` instead of `'test'`, because the following steps are happening:

- `bash` replaces `$PARAMS` with its value
- `bash` tries to execute the line `ruby ./script.rb --val1=test --val2='test'`
- now `bash` sees the quoted value `'test'` and replaces it with `test`, so `ruby` / your script sees `test`